Unexpected Bottom Padding in Bottom App Bar in Android
Question
I'm currently developing an Android application, and I have implemented a Bottom App Bar using the Material Components library. However, when I run the app, I notice an unexpected bottom padding that is affecting the layout of the Bottom App Bar.
I've tried several solutions to resolve this issue, but none have worked. Here are the relevant details about my implementation:
XML Layout
Below is the XML layout snippet where I have defined the Bottom App Bar:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_color"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView

        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomAppBar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/search"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/microphone"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:hint="Search for movies..."
                android:textColorHint="#CCCBCB"/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">

                <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="60dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:text="Category"
                android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/view2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="12dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view2" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:text="Upcomming Movies"
                android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/view3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="12dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view3"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view3"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_blue">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/btn_1"
                        app:tint="@color/orange" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Explorer"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/btn_2"
                        app:tint="@color/orange"  />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Favorite"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/btn_3"
                        app:tint="@color/orange"  />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView14"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Cart"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/btn_4"
                        app:tint="@color/orange"  />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView15"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_conte
                        android:text="Profile"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


The resultnt"

Is this answer answer your question?

can you provide your full project on github

It sounds like the bottom padding issue with your BottomAppBar might be linked to how the layout interacts with system elements like the navigation bar or gesture controls. This is a common issue when using the BottomAppBar component. Here are some practical steps you can try:
make sure your CoordinatorLayout or BottomAppBar is set up to account for system insets. You can do this by adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to the CoordinatorLayout:

i cant even reply with the code updates, i got rid of all errors so i need you to try this, how do indent with 4 spaces, i have tried every button and even manually put 4 x spaces......
Or if you have reddit message me and i can send you this updates XML
AcademicMistake

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
